# Recorrer un json rescatando los ultimos repetidos

Tags: javascript

Este el Objeto Json

```
var data = [
    {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
    {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]},
    {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
    {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
    {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]}
]
```

Esta en la funcion en JavaScript que utilizo:

```
var anios = {};
    var resultado = data.filter(function (e) {
        return anios[e.anioTtile] ? false : (anios[e.anioTtile] = true);
    });
```

Pero el resultado es:

```
var data = [
        {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
        {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
    ]
```

**Lo que deseo es tener solo los años sin repetir y que tenga la información mas completa, refiriéndome a `anioData`, es decir; los últimos array de cada año, o si es posible me permita unificar los que están repetidos**

Ejemplo:

```
var data = [
    {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]},
    {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]}
]
```

Comment: Buenas, una duda, necesitas que los `anioData` se sumen o algo? o como debería de quedar el resultado de cada año? Por ejemplo, el del `2017` cual debería tomar? o debe combinar de algún modo el data?

Comment: Si ,claro como lo muestra en el resultado esperado, seria bueno que  me combinara los datos de cada año

Comment: Claro, por eso pregunto, porque en el resultado esperado no estan "combinados" los datos del 2017, sino que muestra los del "último año 2017" se sumarían? o que necesitas que haga?

Comment: Es correcto, Es eso

Answer (score 1):

Para poder recorrer el objeto JSON de manera correcta, deberías utilizar algunos FOR, y como deseas combinarlos deberás validar de que año se trata para unir los datos que te interesan de cada mes y año.

```js
 var data = [
      {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
      {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]},
      {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
      {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
      {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]}
    ]
    
  var length = data.length;
  var arrFinal = [
    {
      "anioTtile":"2018",
      "anioData":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    {
      "anioTtile":"2017",
      "anioData":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    }
  ]
  
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   var j = 0;

   console.log(data[i].anioTtile);
      switch(data[i].anioTtile)
        {
          case "2018":
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
              arrFinal[0].anioData[j] = arrFinal[0].anioData[j] + (data[i].anioData[j]/1);
            }
            break;
          case "2017":
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
              arrFinal[1].anioData[j] = arrFinal[1].anioData[j] + (data[i].anioData[j]/1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(arrFinal))
```

Para poder juntar la información usé un arreglo de objetos auxiliar, para poder ir llenando la información correspondiente a cada año y cada posición.

La solución claro, esta poco flexible ya que la idea es que veas como puedes implementarlo, ya de ahí puedes eficientarlo un poco para más años o más datos en cada uno.

Creo que se obtiene el resultado deseado, quedo pendiente de tus comentarios :)

Comment: A bueno Mano muchas gracias nuevamente me sacas de apuros, estuve mirando para que fuese claro mas dinámico esta función

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
        {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
        {anioTtile: "2018", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]},
        {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
        {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
        {anioTtile: "2017", anioData:[10000,0,20000,0,50000,0,5000,5000,0,0,0,0]}
    ]  



    var groupBy = function (data, val) {
            return data.reduce(function(grupo, pos) {
                var valor = pos[val];
                grupo[valor] = grupo[valor] || {anioTtile: pos.anioTtile, anioData: []};
                grupo[valor].anioData = pos.anioData;
                return grupo;
            }, {});
        }
        var datas = groupBy(data,'anioTtile');

    console.log(datas);
```

Comment: Ya veo, esta no suma los datos de cada uno verdad? muestra el último de cada año.

Comment: Si es correcto, claro la idea es que si aparece un nuevo año, pueda iterar dinámica mente, pues no se que tan viable sería , aunque me obtiene lo que necesito. Lo que pasa yo utilizo un foreach para traer los datos de la base de datos, pero me los trae asi como esta en el objeto Json inicial, por eso busque lo mas viable